# How to use GCJ with Ant?

Tags: java, ant, gcj

I'm fairly new to both Apache Ant and GCJ, and I'm having a hard time trying to build with GCJ via Ant.

My app is in Scala, so I need to use GCJ to take .class files as source. No problem compiling .scala to .class with Ant.

First I figured out how to manually compile a .class file to .o (object), this way:

```
gcj --classpath=(...) -c (somepath)MouseClickListener.class -o (somepath)MouseClickListener.o
```

I see [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) that Ant supports GCJ compilation through the javac tag. So I figured this should work:

```
<target name="gcjCompile" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${object.dir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${build.dir}"
           destdir="${object.dir}"
           compiler="gcj"
           executable="C:/gcc/gcc-4.3/bin/gcj.exe"
           classpathref="gcjProject.classpath">
        <include name="**/*.class"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

But this javac task does nothing and I get no errors. Any clues?
Thanks

Comment: > My app is in Scala, so I need to use
> GCJ to take .class files as source. That's a *non sequitur*. GCJ is not Java. I can't recommend you use it. If you must have native compilation there are current products out there.

Comment: Which would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to link your app into a native executable. That means that you've already compiled the source into JVM bytecode (as you've figured out to do by compiling .scala into .class files). You'll need to run the `gcj` command manually using the `<exec>` task to compile the bytecode into gcc object code files.

I'd recommend something like this:

```
<property name="main.class" value="Main" />
<property name="class.dir" value="${basedir}/classes" />
<target name="compile">
  <mkdir dir="${class.dir}" />
  <javac srcdir="${build.dir}"
         destdir="${class.dir}"
         compiler="gcj"
         executable="C:/gcc/gcc-4.3/bin/gcj.exe"
         classpathref="gcjProject.classpath">
    <include name="**/*.java"/>
  </javac>
</target>
<target name="link" depends="compile">
  <mkdir dir="${object.dir"} />
  <exec cmd="C:/gcc/gcc-4.3/bin/gcj.exe">
    <arg value="-classpath=${object.dir}" />
    <arg value="-c" />
    <arg value="*.class" />
  </exec>
</target>
```

Keep in mind that you need to define the `build.dir` and `object.dir` properties, and you may need to add a `depends` task before the javac in the compile target (or just recompile from scratch each time). I may have missed a lot of things, you should check the manual pages (for gcj, gcc, and ant) if it doesn't work at first.